# get value Multiple choice listview android

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have developed a multiple choice listview (beginner), my question is how I can make a if statement or switch to the position when check boxes are checked.

I have been looking on internet and I found some examples but is not what I am looking for.

For example this code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String selected = "";

            int cntChoice = myList.getCount();
            SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray 
                              = myList.getCheckedItemPositions();

            for(int i = 0; i < cntChoice; i++){

                if(sparseBooleanArray.get(i)) {
                    selected += myList.getItemAtPosition(i).toString() + "\n";
                }
            }
            Toast.makeText(AndroidListViewActivity.this, 
                    selected, 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }});
```

What does is take all checked check box from the multiple choice putting then into an array. My questions is how I can identify which is it, and depending which is check do something or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok if i understand, you should use this code:

```
btnInstall.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
     public void onClick(View arg0) { 
         String selected = ""; 
         int cntChoice = lvCheckBox.getCount(); 
         SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = lvCheckBox.getCheckedItemPositions(); 
         for(int i = 0; i < cntChoice; i++){ 
             if(sparseBooleanArray.get(i)) { 
                  executeActionBySelectedItem(lvCheckBox.getItemAtPosition(i).toString()); 
            } 
         } 

    }

    private void executeActionBySelectedItem(String selectedItem) {
        if(selectedItem.equals("Action 1")) {
            //execute action 1
        } else if(selectedItem.equals("Action 2")) {
            //execute action 2
        } else if(selectedItem.equals("Action 3")) {
            //execute action 3
        }//...
    }
});
```